# Extreme latency in Django API running on EKS

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, kubernetes, latency, amazon-eks

I have deployed a Django Rest API container on Amazon EKS (Kubernetes) but a simple HttpResponse took around 4-8 seconds.

```
    def home(request):
    return HttpResponse("Homepage")
```

Here is my stack:

- EKS with 3 worker nodes each running on t2.medium (2cpu, 4GB ram)
- ELB: L7 application load-balancer directing requests to 2 different services

  - echoserver: to test simple response time
  - DjangoAPI
- Containers:

  - DjangoAPI
  - Redis - cache
  - echoheaders: Simple echo server (gcr.io/google_containers/echoserver:1.4)

  ```
  NAME                               READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
  pod/djangoapi-65799dd6dc-gkpfp     1/1       Running   0          1h
  pod/echoheaders-5cff747d7d-n4jnt   1/1       Running   0          1h
  pod/redis-7d9fbf54cd-lpffv         1/1       Running   0          1h

  NAME                    TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
  service/djangoapi-svc   NodePort    10.100.41.163    <none>        8000:30327/TCP   11d
  service/echoheaders     NodePort    10.100.94.85     <none>        80:30317/TCP     12d
  service/kubernetes      ClusterIP   10.100.0.1       <none>        443/TCP          35d
  service/redis           ClusterIP   10.100.210.207   <none>        6379/TCP         35d

  NAME                          DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
  deployment.apps/djangoapi     1         1         1            1           11d
  deployment.apps/echoheaders   1         1         1            1           12d
  deployment.apps/redis         1         1         1            1           35d
  ```

When the same DjangoAPI image was deployed to my local setup (minikube), the average response time is around ~200ms.

Dockerfile for Django:

```
FROM python:3.7

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Django Deployment & Service yaml:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: djangoapi
    type: web
  name: djangoapi
  namespace: "default"
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: djangoapi
        type: web
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: djangoapi
        image: wbivan/app:speed
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        args:
        - gunicorn
        - api.wsgi
        - --bind
        - 0.0.0.0:8000
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "64Mi"
            cpu: "250m"
          limits:
            memory: "128Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
        envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: djangoapi-config
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8000
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred
      restartPolicy: Always

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: djangoapi-svc
  namespace: "default"
  labels:
    app: djangoapi
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8000
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8000
  selector:
    app: djangoapi
    type: web
  type: NodePort
```

### Things I've tried

1. Adjusting EC2 instance size from t2.small to t2.medium
2. Adding more DjangoAPI replicas on Kubernetes deployment (from 1 to 3)
3. Setting and removing resources limits on each deployment.

   ```
   resources:
     requests:
       memory: "64Mi"
       cpu: "250m"
     limits:
       memory: "128Mi"
       cpu: "500m"
   ```

**but not much difference was made using the above methods**

4. Then I suspect the Elastic Load-balancer was the problem. Which is why I deployed the echo server (using the image gcr.io/google_containers/echoserver:1.4). But most request only took **~50ms**.

   ```
   # This took ~50ms
     - host: echo.mydomain.com
       http:
         paths:
         - path: /*
           backend:
             serviceName: echoheaders
             servicePort: 80

   # This took ~ 8000ms!!!
     - host: django.mydomain.com
       http:
         paths:
         - path: /*
           backend:
             serviceName: djangoapi-svc
             servicePort: 8000
   ```
5. So clearly the django service was the problem. To verify that, I compared the same deployment on EKS and my local machine (minikube). I tried to isolate my test on just the service itself using `kubectl port-forward deployment/djangoapi 7000:8000`

   - Django service on **Minikube**: ~ 200ms
   - Django service on **EKS**: 4000-8000 ms

### Observations

1. What I have noticed is that the response time on my EKS deployment varies a lot. Most of the response took 4-8 seconds, but occasionally it would only take 150ms.
2. Using the EC2 monitors, all 3 nodes were running at 2.5% CPU utilization, peaks at 8%.
3. Before this project was dockerized and deployed using Kubernetes, the django code was hosted on a single t2.meduim instance running on ubuntu with Nginx. The average response time was **~300ms**. So I'm pretty sure the Django API itself shouldn't be causing the slowdown.

I understand it is unfair to compare a local deployment as the networking is simpler and the resources available might be different (2cpu 2.3GHz i5 Mac, 2GB ram) but this is a startling difference.

Does anyone have a similar experience and any suggestions on how to further debug the situation?

Comment: Can you provide the Dockerfile for your django service? Are you writing anything to disk? Please provide the deployment manifest for the django service as well

Comment: @Thomas I'm not writing anything to disk at all. There are some urls which would trigger a look up to a RDS database, but the url that I'm profiling with only involves a simple HttpResponse. Also I've added dockerfile and yaml files :)

Comment: You are positive that you are not writing anything to disk, not even logfiles, so you get the logging from stdout? I would start adding log statements to determine the root cause of the latency. In addition I don't see the redis cache container in your manifests. how is it deployed, how do the app access it?

Comment: After spending some time investigating, I realize it has to do with gunicorn with django. For some reason as soon as I remove gunicorn and just run the django with python manage.py runserver, this immediately speed up the service and takes around 50ms to respond. I know running with python manage.py is a bad idea, but I'm still figuring out the exact problem

Comment: @Ivan did you manage to get your django application to run using Gunicorn?

Comment: @NicholasColes No, I took out Gunicorn for now and I deployed more replicas for precautionary measures. I've seen posts of others suffering from similar problem working with ELB and have no simple solutions.

Comment: @Ivan have you logged a support case with AWS? Also, which versions of Gunicorn / EKS are you running?

Comment: Did you find any concrete conclusion as to why you were facing this latency issue on EKS?